# How to schedule a task to open a program every 3 minutes?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-10

I know there are some other questions about this, but how do I set the task scheduler to open a file/program every x minutes starting right after the task was ran.

I'm making a program that has a script that has to be ran every 3 minutes and the best way is the task scheduler.

I have tried messing with the settings and I found "Repeat task every x minutes" but the problem with that is I have to set the starting time and I don't want that. I want it to start repeatin the task as soon as it was started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine a task that runs on login with a batch script that loops endlessly [running the program](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001345.htm) you want every 3 minutes.